# Who is "Ansar" in Sahih al-Bukhari 17?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

[Sahih al-Bukhari 17](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/10):

> **Narrated Anas:**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Love for the **Ansar** is a sign of faith and
> hatred for the Ansar is a sign of hypocrisy."

**Is it a name or referring to local inhabitants of Medina?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the inhabitants of Medinah among the sahaba, as in the verse:

> والسابقون الأولون من المهاجرين و**الأنصار** والذين اتبعوهم بإحسان رضي الله عنهم ورضوا عنه وأعد لهم جنات تجري تحتها الأنهار خالدين فيها أبدا ذلك الفوز العظيم
>
> And the first forerunners [in the faith] among the Muhajireen and the **Ansar** and those who followed them with good conduct - Allah is pleased with them and they are pleased with Him, and He has prepared for them gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they will abide forever. That is the great attainment.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:100](http://quran.com/9/100)</sup>

Comment: What about present inhabitants of Medinah? Should we love them and not hate?

Comment: @Bahrom They are not Ansar. You should love and not hate all Muslims, but this hadith is not applicable to them.

Comment: @Bahrom Yes, Muhajireen are the sahaba who migrated from Makkah to Medinah. Ansar are the sahaba who were inhabitants of Medinah at that time and are called so because of their aid to the Prophet and the Muhajireen.

Comment: Jazakallahu hairun